# Why the k 'don't reset after compile?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try the BEGAN and adjust the loss_weights by k value. It worked in the pass, but which is not useful in recent.

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

k_var = 0.0
k = K.variable(k_var)

d_train.compile(loss=['mae','mae'],loss_weights=[1.,-k],optimizer=opt)

for step, batch in enumerate(data):
    g_seed = np.random.uniform(0.1, 1, (32, 32))
    g_loss = g.train_on_batch(g_seed, batch)
    
    g_pred = g.predict(g_seed)
    
    total, real_loss, fake_loss = d_train.train_on_batch([batch, g_pred],[batch, g_pred])
    
    k_var += LR_K*(GAMMA*real_loss - g_loss)
    k_var = max(min(k_var, 1), 0)
    
    K.set_value(k, k_var)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to reset the k value in the loss_wights which in the compile after each training. After per training, I'll get a new k_var and set the value to k. But it doesn't work. k is still the same as it was in the beginning.